# Find row that have a duplicate field, the filed type is blob

Tags: mysql, duplicates, blob

I have a table with many many duplicated row, I cannot create a unique value for the blob field, because is too large.

How can I find and delete the duplicate rows where the blob field (answer) is duplicated?

This is the table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer` blob NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enabled` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `spam` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `correct` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notification_send` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `correct_notification` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_question` (`id_question`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `enabled` (`enabled`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1488 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: How large is `large`?

Comment: based on your doubt i manually delete all the duplicated answers and create an unique index.  :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probable you can use prefix of the column by `substr() or left()` and compare. How much size you want to take that depends on your data distribution or prefix uniqueness of the column data. 
for uniqueness check you can fire the below query if the

```
select count(distinct left(answer, 128))/count(*), count(distinct left(answer, 256))/count(*) from answers.
```

This will provide you selectivity or data distribution in your column. suppose 128 gives you answer as 1 `i.e. all unique if you take first 128 bytes` then choose that amount of data from each row and work. Hope it helps.